# Best practice for handling SQL injections when calling a stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection

I have inherited code that I am fixing security holes up. What's the best practice for handling SQL injections when a stored procedure is called?

The code is something like:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("");

sql.Append(string.Format("Sp_MyStoredProc '{0}', {1}, {2}", sessionid, myVar, "0"));


using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Main"].ToString()))
{
    cn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), cn))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandTimeout = 10000;
        returnCode = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

I just do the same thing with a regular SQL query and add the parameters using `AddParameter` correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Q. What's the Best practice for Handling SQL injections?

A. Use [parameterised queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx)

example:

> ```
> using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
> {
>     // Create the command and set its properties.
>     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
>     command.Connection = connection;
>     command.CommandText = "SalesByCategory";
>     command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>
>     // Add the input parameter and set its properties.
>     SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
>     parameter.ParameterName = "@CategoryName";
>     parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
>     parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
>     parameter.Value = categoryName;
>
>     // Add the parameter to the Parameters collection.
>     command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
>
>     // Open the connection and execute the reader.
>     connection.Open();
>     SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
>     .
>     .
>     .
> }
> ```