# Stored Procedures, ExecuteScalar and Parametes

Tags: .net, sql, stored-procedures, sqlparameter

I have a stored procedure that I call like this:

```
string proc = "SpCreate '00111', 3";

 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(proc, conn))
 {
       command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       command.CommandTimeout = 1000;

       string returnCode = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
 }
```

The above gode works fine. But once I add in a parameter, I get the incorrect syntax near 'SpCreate'. What gives? (Code below causes error.)

```
string proc = "SpCreate '00111', @myId";

 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(proc, conn))
 {
       SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter("@myId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 3 };
       command.Parameters.Add(paramName);

       command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       command.CommandTimeout = 1000;

       string returnCode = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Which DB interface are you using? OleDb likes parameters that start with @, but SqlDb prefers place-holders like ?.  Also, have you tried using "exec SpCreate '00111', @myId"?

Answer (score 0):

Edited my answer after looking at some of my own code and realizing I had some errors.

You need to set the CommandType to StoredProcedure.

Edit: Example Source Code added

```
 string proc = "SpCreate";

 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(proc, conn))
 {
       SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter("@myId", SqlDbType.Int);
       paramName.Value = 3;
       command.Parameters.Add(paramName);

       command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       command.CommandTimeout = 1000;

       string returnCode = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Neither removing/adding the @ did anything. And adding EXEC made a errror converting from nvarchar to int.

Comment: can you describe the value you are putting into proc? Is SpCreate the name of a stored procedure? If it is, is the parameter declared in the Stored Procedure?

Comment: This is how it needs to be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905917/best-practice-for-handling-sql-injections-when-calling-a-stored-procedure/14905927#14905927

Comment: @chris - I agree that is a correct example, but it is not exactly what you are doing. I still need you to answer my question. Is "SpCreate" the name of the stored procedure, and if so, in that stored procedure do you initialize a parameter called "@myId"?

Comment: Yes spCreate is a name of the stored procedure and the myId is a value passed in (for security reasons I change my code to dummy text)

Comment: @chris - then try the sample code I added to my answer. You need to set your CommandType as StoredProcedure and then just give the name of the stored procedure to the Command. Then set the parameter as I showed and it should work. This format matches the link you provided earlier in these comments.